# return 3 most recent records for a list of serial numbers

Tags: mysql

This is stripped down copy of my serial number table.

```
id            serial number
---------------------------
1064    1012507994
1065    1012507994
1067    1019527101
1436    1012507994
1437    1012507994
1438    1012507994
1439    1012507994
1464    1019527101
1465    1019527101
```

Every time I add another record to this table the id is incremented. 
I want to be able to pass in a list of serial_numbers and get the last 3 id for each of the serial numbers I pass in. I know how to return the last 3 id's for one serial number but I can't figure out now get the last 3 id for a list of serial numbers.

eg: I want to get the last (most recent) 3 records for serial number in (12507994,19527101)
The results should be

```
1439    12507994
1438    12507994
1437    12507994
1067    19527101
1464    19527101
1465    19527101
```

Answer (score 1):

You need
 1. Select last 2 seriral numbers.
 2. SElect last 3 records of this numbers

```
SELECT   * 
FROM you_table
WHERE SERIAL number IN 
  (SELECT serial_number FROM you_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 1) 
LIMIT 0, 3 
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM you_table
WHERE SERIAL number IN 
  (SELECT serial_number FROM you_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1) 
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks Like I'll have to move to a different version of MYSQL. I get SQL execution error #1235  This version of MySQl doesn't yet support 'Limit & IN/All/ANY/SOME subquery. The MYSQL version I'm using is 5.5.32 on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is use UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE serial_number = '12507994' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3
UNION
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE serial_number = '19527101' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had to put parentheses around each of the select statements to get this to run otherwise it gave me an error saying Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY